How can I find the color space of my display?
I would like to know what the color space of my laptop screen is.  (i. e., is it sRGB, Display-P3, or something else?)
How can I find this out under Linux?
I know that I can get the ICC profile of the display by doing:
xprop -root _ICC_PROFILE

and I suppose I could write a script to convert that comma-separated list of integers into a binary file.  But even then, how would I know what it means?  Is there some program that will analyze an ICC profile and tell me what named color space it is closest to?  (i. e. sRGB, Display-P3, Rec2020, ProPhoto, etc.)
System info
I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS, using X11 and the default desktop environment (Gnome 3, I guess?)
Motivation
When I call XParseColor() with an XYZ color string, such as CIEXYZ:0.781853/0.803188/1.018247, the RGB triple I'm getting back is significantly different than if I convert from XYZ to sRGB myself, using the standard equations.  So I'm guessing that means my display is not using sRGB.  But I'd like to confirm my suspicion, and find out what it's using instead.
Update (2024-04-30)
I converted the output of xprop -root _ICC_PROFILE into a binary file, and ran exiftool on it.  This is the result:
ExifTool Version Number         : 12.69
File Name                       : profile.icc
Directory                       : /tmp
File Size                       : 1404 bytes
File Modification Date/Time     : 2024:04:30 13:34:59-07:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2024:04:30 13:34:59-07:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2024:04:30 13:34:59-07:00
File Permissions                : -rw-rw-r--
File Type                       : ICC
File Type Extension             : icc
MIME Type                       : application/vnd.iccprofile
Profile CMM Type                : Little CMS
Profile Version                 : 4.3.0
Profile Class                   : Display Device Profile
Color Space Data                : RGB
Profile Connection Space        : XYZ
Profile Date Time               : 2021:09:25 21:48:37
Profile File Signature          : acsp
Primary Platform                : Apple Computer Inc.
CMM Flags                       : Not Embedded, Independent
Device Manufacturer             :
Device Model                    :
Device Attributes               : Reflective, Glossy, Positive, Color
Rendering Intent                : Perceptual
Connection Space Illuminant     : 0.9642 1 0.82491
Profile Creator                 : Little CMS
Profile ID                      : 6bbae4088b7362ecc6dce845070fefe3
Profile Description             : Pangolin
Profile Copyright               : This profile is free of known copyright restrictions.
Media White Point               : 0.9642 1 0.82491
Chromatic Adaptation            : 1.04576 0.02182 -0.04947 0.02797 0.99156 -0.01675 -0.0092 0.01505 0.75375
Red Matrix Column               : 0.41263 0.24045 0.0302
Blue Matrix Column              : 0.1601 0.13902 0.69208
Green Matrix Column             : 0.39146 0.62053 0.10263
Red Tone Reproduction Curve     : (Binary data 16 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Green Tone Reproduction Curve   : (Binary data 16 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Blue Tone Reproduction Curve    : (Binary data 16 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Chromaticity Channels           : 3
Chromaticity Colorant           : Unknown
Chromaticity Channel 1          : 0.58984 0.34961
Chromaticity Channel 2          : 0.33008 0.55469
Chromaticity Channel 3          : 0.15332 0.11914
CMF product                     : gnome-settings-daemon
DATA source                     : edid
EDID manufacturer               : Chimei Innolux Corporation
EDID md 5                       : 3f1fa6a95bf0f6d4c3a4760f7ef81578
CMF binary                      : gnome-settings-daemon
EDID mnft                       : CMN
CMF version                     : 3.36.1
MAPPING device id               : xrandr-Chimei Innolux Corporation
Device Mfg Desc                 : Chimei Innolux Corporation
Device Model Desc               : Pangolin

I still don't know what it means, though.  How can I compare the gamut of my display to known colorspaces like sRGB, Display-P3, Rec2020, etc.?
